# Is there anyone who knows how to make a db migration files in Laminas php?

Tags: zend-framework, migration, command-line-interface, database-migration, laminas

I am going to make a db migration file and migrate the file to database by using the a command.
But I can't find the command.

In Laravel we approach the goal by using this command.

```
php artisan make:migrate migration_client_table
```

Is there any similiar command that acts like the `php artisan make:migrate` command?

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Laravel/Symfony background as well, I was asking this myself. Here are my findings:

Laminas uses laminad-db module for interactions with database. [Documentation](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-db/) for this module however does not mention migrations at all.

[Database and Models](https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/) introduction to Laminas uses sql file to create a table and fill it with some original seed and does not mention altering tables at all.

Therefore I made assumption Laminas does not handle migrations at all.

Edit: According to [this](https://discourse.laminas.dev/t/database-migrations/2960/2?u=johnyprokie) answer, we can use sqitch, doctrine/migrations or liquibase